# Secure VPN between Windows/Linux servers guide?

Tags: linux, windows, vpn

What is the best and (ideally simplest) way to place several Windows Server 2012 and Linux (Ubuntu) machines under a VPN?

The purpose is to provide secure connectivity to services (eg, databases) via private IPs and of course encryption for insecure protocols.

My requirements are:

1. Windows and Linux support
2. Simplicity / maintainability :)

Any recommendations?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Site to site VPNs via the routers or firewalls on each end will be the best bet.  This way any device added to the remote network is allowed over the VPN.

Comment: Thanks Denny. Is there a suitable way to do this without hardware? I have VMs in one data center, cloud servers in another, and dedicated servers in yet another. So just connecting them all on the same VPN would be great.

Comment: You could setup a VM or physical server at each site and have those three machines VPN to each other.  Then setup routes on each of the other machines so that network traffic for the remote site is directed through the VPN machine as a secondary gateway.  Wouldn't be the easiest way to do it, but very doable.

Answer (score -1):

yes, site-to-site works best, since you offload the VPN from the server, but if your routers are not s2s capable, you can easily set up OpenVPN

http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/overview.html

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.